# Multi-threading in recursive methods

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion, synchronization

According to the following code:

```
synchronized int x(int y) {
    int m;

    class statement extends Thread {

            @Override
            void run() {
                //Some Statements    
                if (condition) {
                   m = x(someValue);
                }    
                //other statements
            }
     }
     //some statements

     statement st = new statement();
     st.start;
     return m;
}
```

every time that program invokes `x(int y)`, it will create a new thread.

Now, When program invokes `x()` for the second time, the lock of the object is acquired by outer thread (the thread in the first invocation). So the thread in second invocation (inner thread) will acquire the object or it will be blocked?

Regards

Comment: This is really strange code - I have never seen before - and it does not make any sense to use threads and the blocking of x with synchronized.

Comment: @TobiasOtto can you please explain more? why it doesn't make sense?

Comment: I would start a new thread if i have a _long running calculation_ and want the _main programm_ run or if  i have a lot of _complex calculations_ and want that more than one cpu/core is working on the calculations in parallel. In your example the blocking of the method x prohibit any  another thread.

Comment: Just so you know, "outer" and "inner" are _your_ words.  Java does not remember or care which thread started which other thread.

Comment: @TobiasOtto thanks. so i need to start learn to work with *thread-pool*. but my last question, what happens if i remove *synchronized* modifier?

Comment: Multi-threading should not be used here. This is sequential process one method wait for the return value for the method it has called so starting that many threads won't do any parallelism.
Let's take an example of finding nth value in fibonacci series using recursion. here every value contributes to next value in fibonacci so until you don't have (n-1)th value you can't find nth value so it is sequential process.so each thread will have to wait until the thread it has called finishes.
This is similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

That keyword there makes sure that only **one** thread can invoke `x()` at any point in time.

But: you can't predict if the **outer** thread is still within that method or not.

And just for the record: don't do that. Don't write "real" code like this.

Comment: I would never write codes like this. I just started multi-threading programming and some question are stuck to my brain, I need to find an answer..

Comment: Wrong. The outer thread creates and starts the inner one and then returns. There is nothing in there that would make it wait!

Comment: You mean when program goes through `if` statement, while the `x` method is running again, the thread that invokes it, will continue its task?!

Comment: Exactly. Nothing prevents the outer thread from leaving the method after starting the inner thread. But honestly I am actually surprised that this even compiles, as I have no clue what this method is supposed to return in the end.

Comment: well, i've thought that outer thread wouldn't continue till the inner one returns. that's a important note. tnx